# Is there a way to search whole table for a specific keyword using Django ORM?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, keyword

I need to search whole table (django model) for a keyword given by user. It's going to be further used as a boolean search feature.

My idea was to dynamically add Q objects but I have failed to implement that.
Are there any other useful ORM methods I should use? Or am I stuck with SQL injection?

Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: What about [***`icontains`***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-icontains) lookup?

Comment: I was using icontains while building Q objects, but it didn't work as expected, or maybe the way I was trying to dynamically add them to the queryset filters was invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `PostgreSQL` you can take a look at Django's [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#django.contrib.postgres.search.SearchVector) implementation or just go through the django [search docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/search/)

Otherwise a 3rd party lib like [django-haystack](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/) which can index and search across multiple fields and adds additional search benefits.

Comment: I am using Postgres indeed, let me try that, looks promising! Somehow I've overlooked that while browsing through docs